# Choosing category for uploading text

Tags: php, upload, categories

I'm building sort of a text upload site. When you post a text on this site: http://www.youngcreativity.se/post.php

I want to have a button where you can choose a category of your text.

And when a user choose for example Poem, his/her text should upload to the category Poem.

Please, help me!

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you just need to add a "name" property to your select box, like

```
<select name="category">...</select>
```

Comment: Look at your code, line 78: <select> -- You need to make it say "<select name="category">.

Comment: You should follow this tutorial on adding content to a database: http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: @DavidGabor it's clearly an involved tutorial and not something you'll understand without putting some thought and effort to it. I suggest spending an hour or two on it when you find time and then come back with questions, and you'll be surprised how eager people are to help you.

Comment: Ok, now I understand it better.. So I should create 3 fields in my database: Novel, Quote and Poem. Then connect to the database. But how can I make so that if I choose Poem in the dropdown menu on my website it recognize which category?